# Average time based on file count and GB

Tags: powershell, calculation

basically this is gonna sound dumb but cant work it out for love nor money.
I want to calculate the average time it would take to scan files based on totalGB and number offiles. need both because some files would be much larger or smaller and would affect the output.

Working in powershell as part of a script. an example here. so roughly i would be expecting the answer to come out around 40. now this is close but im not entirely sure its there

```
`$SizeGB = 4
    $FileCount = 4000

    $examples = @(
    @{TimeSeconds = 10; SizeGB = 1; Files = 1000},
    @{TimeSeconds = 20; SizeGB = 2; Files = 2000},
    @{TimeSeconds = 30; SizeGB = 3; Files = 3000},
    @{TimeSeconds = 50; SizeGB = 5; Files = 5000},
    @{TimeSeconds = 60; SizeGB = 6; Files = 6000}
 
    )

    # Calculate average processing time per GB and per file based on examples
   $totalTime = 0
    $totalSize = 0
    $totalFiles = 0

   foreach ($example in $examples) {
    $totalTime += $example.TimeSeconds
    $totalSize += $example.SizeGB
    $totalFiles += $example.Files
    }

    $averageTimePerExample = $totalTime / $examples.Count
    $averageGBPerExample = ($totalSize + $SizeGB) / ($examples.Count + 1)
    $averageFilesPerExample = ($totalFiles + $FileCount) / ($examples.Count + 1)
 
    $sizeRatio = $SizeGB / $averageGBPerExample
    $fileCountRatio = $FileCount / $averageFilesPerExample

    $estimatedTotalTime = $averageTimePerExample * $sizeRatio * $fileCountRatio`
```

tried multiple things. but i think im there and hope this can help someone one day

Comment: The trick is in figuring out what 'scan' means, because it's entirely likely that from one file to the next the scan time will vary depending on more factors than just byte size.

Comment: You need to measure the time taken for some less "symmetrical" examples - in all of your current ones the file count and total size increase exactly in proportion with each other (1Gb / 1000 files, 2Gb / 2000 files, 3Gb / 3000 files, etc) so you can't isolate the effect of file count vs total size. Ideally you'd keep one constant while varying the other (1Gb / 1000 files, 2Gb, /1000 file, 3Gb / 1000 files) and then do the same with the other (1Gb / 1000 files, 1Gb / 2000 files, 1 Gb / 3000 files).

Comment: ... you can then plot graphs with your two datasets, and if you see two straight lines you can try to solve "simultaneous linear equations" to get a formula for total time based on X Gb and Y file count. But as @Gregory suggests, the reality is that performance is dependent on a number of practical factors (e.g. are overnight backups running at the same time in PROD,, is the perf test machine memory bound whereas PROD is cpu bound? etc) which means it's all a bit of a finger-in-the-air guess anyway...

Comment: @mclayton. It's best endeavours of estimating for a progress bar. Based on previous examples. And  I do have a proper dataset with varying examples. This was just me trying to get an answer roughly in the ballpark I was expecting. The more I add the better it will be hopefully. But good idea on changing one variable and looking at the graphs. It's gonna always run on one machine, but yeah lots of outside factors. ...and it hurts my head. 
Thanks.

Comment: What you are probably trying to do is the `min/max(MyFileCount * AvgTimePerFile, MySize * AvgTimePerSize)`; however this approach has some assumptions which may make it invalid to use in this situation: is size vs time linear, is avg a good central measure, does data type(exe, zip, txt, xlsx, bin, enc, ...) affect scan time, is a file scanned faster if it's already been scanned once before

Comment: @Gregory. yeah its a bit of a problem. as is everything when trying to give estimated times / progress bars. so many variables. (i  wanted to just put. "scanning... please wait" :)"
yes depending on the file type and size it can change a lot. was thinking of adding in variables such as for .exe >10kb extend time by X
but thats probably gonna get waaay out of hand. 
but you are correct. maybe average maybe isnt the best approach due to the nature.. might be the closest example. 
also seems to affect scan time depending on free size as well. so 1kb in a 2gb drive is quicker than 1kb in 2tb